# Django Rest Framework: как получить текущий суперпользователь в serialize?

Tags: python, django

Есть `CreateApiView`:

```
class CreateEmployeeApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
# authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, ]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
queryset = Employee.objects.all()
serializer_class = CreateEmployeeApiSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(CreateEmployeeApiView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

и `serializer`:

```
class CreateEmployeeApiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', required=True)
email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email', required=True)
password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password',
                                 style={'input_type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'},
                                 write_only=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = (
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'is_delete',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'father_name',
        'birth',
        'avatar',
        'status',
    )

def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(CreateEmployeeApiSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    status = instance.status
    data['status'] = Employee.USER_ROLE[status - 1][1]
    data['author'] = instance.author.username
    data['user'] = instance.user.username
    return data

def create(self, validated_data):
    # Create new user
    print(validated_data)
    user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['user']['username'],
                               email=validated_data['user']['email'])
    user.set_password(validated_data['user']['password'])
    user.save()

    # Create employee
    super_user = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
    print()
    employee = Employee(user=user)
    employee.is_delete = validated_data['is_delete']
    employee.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
    employee.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
    employee.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
    employee.father_name = validated_data['father_name']
    employee.birth = validated_data['birth']
    employee.avatar = validated_data['avatar']
    employee.status = validated_data['status']
    employee.author = user
    employee.save()
    return employee
```

Мне нужен именно `superuser`, а не простой `user`. Когда создается `employee`, поля `employee.author` должен присвоить вошедший пользователь (т.е. текущую `superuser`). Как мне это сделать? Я надеюсь, вы правильно поняли меня!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите текущего пользователя из `request`

Получить `request` можно так:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        request=kwargs.get('context').get('request')
```

Но думаю можно найти способ по лучше